# Making Computer local server

Tags: android, database, sqlite, database-connection, localserver

I want to make my laptop local server for my app developing. SQLite database will drop into this server and my app will call all operations from the server database. Database is ready, but don't know how to make my laptop local server to drop database to the server.

Comment: Then you have to install a server application on your laptop and let it run. That's the start. Further it is unclear what kind of server you want.

Comment: For only using my database. My app will call every data from that database which it include to this server. You know what I mean?

Comment: No. I dont. And that did not make it better. No info about server type given.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is a serverless data base. You can look towards hosting SQL servers on local computers. The given link is useful :
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh272703(v=vs.103).aspx